# Logics in Postgres queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

*This is the second attempt as I didn't add enough examples in the first one and it was closed.*

I need to make a query in Postgres that inserts new item if existing data has invalid data. I want to do something like this

```sql
if not exists( select * from table where field='value' ) then
    insert into ...
end if;
```

Can I do this without functions?

Here's the table

```sql
create table if not exists test_md (
    id          serial  not null,
    partition   text    not null,
    version     int     not null,
    data        jsonb   not null,
    
    primary key (partition, version)
);
```

Here's some data

```sql
insert into test_md(partition, version, data) 
values
    ('part one', 1, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}'),
    ('part one', 2, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}'),
    ('part two', 4, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}'),
    ('part two', 5, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}')
;
```

For example I want to insert data set

```json
{
    'partition': 'part one', 
    'data':      '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}'
}
```

I should do nothing if `partition` and `data` are the same with the `v2` record. In any other case, I should add a new record with version `max + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction would look like this (written in a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement in PL/pgSQL):

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   r test_md;
   new_version integer;
BEGIN
   -- get the latest version and lock it
   SELECT * INTO r
   FROM test_md
   WHERE partition = 'part one'
   ORDER BY version DESC
   FOR UPDATE
   LIMIT 1;

   -- if "data" has not changed, we are done
   IF r.data = JSONB '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}' THEN
      RETURN;
   END IF;

   new_version := coalesce(r.version, 0) + 1;

   INSERT INTO test_md (partition, version, data)
   VALUES ('part one', new_version, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}');
END;$$;
```

Of course you can write the same logic as a database function or using client code, but make sure that it is running in a single transaction.

Comment: It might be worth linking to [the manual page for `DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html), since one of the key insights here is that you can use that to run procedural code outside of a function.

Comment: It reports an error 
```ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block```.
I think I will figure out what's the reason. The idea is clear. Thanks

Comment: Close the broken transaction before running the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with a single statement using a [data modifying common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), although I'm not sure if this is more efficient that Laurenz' procedural code:

```
with new_data (partition, data) as (
  values ('part one', '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v3"}'::jsonb)
), latest as (
  select t.*
  from test_md t
  where t.partition = (select nd.partition from new_data nd)
  order by version desc
  limit 1
)
insert into test_md (partition, data, version)
select nd.partition, 
       nd.data,
       (select coalesce(max(version), 0) + 1 
        from test_md md where md.partition = nd.partition)
from new_data nd
where not exists (select * 
                  from latest e
                  where e.partition = nd.partition 
                    and e.data = nd.data)
```